# How to display a Multi-line asp.net Button in a IE10 browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10

I have a button on my web site where the text property is multiline.

```
<asp:Button CssClass="button" 
            ID="submitOrderButton" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="line 1&#10;line 2&#10;line 3" 
            Height="80px" Width="150px"  />
```

This button displays as expected on the most common web browsers.

However I can not get the text to display correctly when viewing my web site in IE10.

The application is deploying .Net 4.0.  Editor VS 2012.

Can anyone else confirm that this behaviour is specific to the IE 10 browser.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why do you need three lines of text on the button?

Comment: Image button, Seems IE 10 specific here as well good sir :D

Answer (score 1):

That´s simple On VB.net -->

Your_button.Text = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Word"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AAP.

This worked for me with C#, IE 10 & VS2012.

```
Your_Button.Text = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "World";
```

Please +1 if this helps...